# i constructed a simple http server, when response data contains "*http", * can be any strings short than 5 characters,the browser received nothing

Tags: java, http, server

i constructed a simple http server, when response data contains "*http", * can be any strings short than 5 characters ,the client browser received nothing. but  when response data contains "http" surrounded by string longer than 5 chars ,the client can get it

Server code,in a designated port listen

```html
public class HttpServer {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);
   while (true) {
    Socket socket = server.accept();
//    System.out.println("客户端IP地址："+socket.getInetAddress());
    HttpSession session = new HttpSession(socket);
    new Thread(session).start();
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

process the request

```html
public class HttpSession implements Runnable {
 private Socket socket ;

 public HttpSession(Socket socket){
  super();
  this.socket = socket;
 }

 public void run() {
         try {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
   OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream();
   String command = null;
   while((command = br.readLine()) != null){
//    System.out.println("浏览器的指令:"+command);
    if(command.length() <3){
     break;
    }
    String result = command.substring(0,3);
    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
     int begin = command.indexOf("/")+1;
     int end=command.lastIndexOf(" ");
     String parameters = command.substring(begin,end);
     
     System.out.println(parameters);
     parameters = URLDecoder.decode(parameters, "utf-8");
     System.out.println("key"+parameters);
     if(!parameters.contains("."))
      doGet(parameters,out);
     break;
    }
    
   }
   out.close();
   br.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 private void doGet(String key, OutputStream out) {
  System.out.println(key+"-------");
   
  List<String> list=WillDelete.getImages(key);
  String data="<html>";
  for(String t:list){
   data+="<img src='"+t+"'/>";
  }
  data+="</html>";// response with this, the client can receive data
//  data="<imghttp</2>";//response with this, the client can receive noting
  try {
   
    out.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
   
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this program many times with different strings and i cannot find the answer. Suddenly i think that it's a http request and it's supposed to return a http response. then i look up something about http. i find http is consists of four parts:

＜status-line＞

＜headers＞

＜blank line＞

[＜response-body＞]

the following is an example:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Dec 2005 23:59:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 122

＜html＞

＜head＞

＜title＞Wrox Homepage＜/title＞

＜/head＞

＜body＞

＜!-- body goes here --＞
＜/body＞

＜/html＞

so, the browser must consider it as an http response header.